# How to create a fixed Text label in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to create a label on a Textfield that remains fixed in position. I have an app on my phone which has labels as shown below, and am trying to design something similar:

[image]

As seen, the labels are always there fixed in position whether someone typed in the field or not. I typed 'Jay' in the `Customer Contact Field`
With my current code the label starts inside the field then moves to hang at the border. Or maybe its not possible with flutter?

```
child:TextField(
       decoration: InputDecoration(
       labelText: 'Customer Contact')),
```

Answer (score 5):

You can add `Text` and `TextField` into `Column` widget to achieve this:

```
    Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('Customer Contact', textAlign: TextAlign.left),
        TextField(
          cursorColor: Colors.white,
          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter here'),
        )
      ],
    );
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should keep everything inside the **TextField** so that it can manage automatically the validation flow style.

```
InputDecoration(
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    label: Container(
        child: Text(
            widget.title,
        ),
    ),
    floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
)
```